# How to use pd.DataFrame.rolling.corr() with Kendall's Tau or Spearman

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Just like the title suggests, is there a built-in way to do alternative correlation methods on top of df.rolling()? I am aware of df.rolling.apply(), but was hoping for something built-in instead.

```
# Example
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,100,9],
                   'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

# These work, but are not what I want
df.rolling(3).corr()
df.corr(method='kendall')
>>> True

# This is what I want to do
df.rolling(3).corr(method='kendall')
>>> TypeError: count() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

Comment: For Spearman, see: [Pandas Rolling window Spearman correlation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186624/)

Comment: Thanks. Why isn't this built-in?